# Group prefix inside group prefix in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Do prefixes inside prefixes work? I tried next example:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'section'), function() {
    Route::get('page', function() {
        return 'page';
    });

    Route::group(array('prefix' => 'subsection'), function() {
        Route::get('subpage', function() {
            return 'subpage';
        });
    });
});
```

I'm able to get to /section/page but not /section/subsection/subpage. I tried different syntax but without success.

**Update: Actually it works, I think I made a type somewhere**

Comment: This should work. If it's not then you've got some conflicting routes somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

By your own testing, prefixes inside prefixes is not supported.  This will work however:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'section'), function() {
    Route::get('page', function() {
        return 'page';
    });
});

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'section/subsection'), function() {
    Route::get('subpage', function() {
        return 'subpage';
    });
});
```

Might not be optimal for what you're looking for, but still allows for grouping the 2nd level routes.

Comment: Perhaps it is worth issuing this against Laravel as either a bug or potential future functionality.

Comment: So - oddly enough, I just tested @victor 's original code. Locally, it worked fine for me.

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'section'), function() {
    Route::get('page', function() {
        return 'page';
    });

    Route::group(array('prefix' => 'subsection'), function() {
        Route::get('subpage', function() {
            return 'subpage';
        });
        Route::get('subpage3', function() {
            return 'subpage3';
        });
    });
});

All 3 routes worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Weird, could be a typo in Victor's actual application code instead of what he posted above, or an earlier version of Laravel 4. I'd suggest running `composer update` to get to the current version (4.0.5) and see if that fixes anything.